# UITableViewCell not being called correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a cell class like below:

```
class DocumentPartCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var documentPartTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var documentPartNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var documentPartProgress: UILabel!
    var documentPart: DocumentPart? {
        didSet {
            if let documentPart = documentPart {
                self.documentPartTitle.text = documentPart.title
                self.documentPartNumber.text = "\(documentPart.partNumber)"
            }
        }
}
}
```

And as you can see, documentPart contains data.

If I understand correctly, didSet should input data from documentPart to documentPartTitle and documentPartNumber.

In `cellForRowIndexPath` I do like following:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let documentPartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("documentPartCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DocumentPartCell
return documentPartCell
}
```

However, when the tableview is showed on `UIViewController`, it doesn't trigger didSet function here. I set the break point in the middle of didSet method.But it hits `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. What am I doing wrong? I'm just trying to delegate all jobs to cell class to input values in `UILabel`.

Comment: Where are you setting **documentPart** property of  DocumentPartCell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be something like that:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let documentPartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("documentPartCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DocumentPartCell
   documentPartCell.documentPart = documentPartCommingFromTheDataSource   
   return documentPartCell
 }
```